# Migration to convert array of string to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

what is the migration to convert a column template_id of data_type array of string to integer?

Example:

A row has template_id with value ["2"]. I want it to be 2.

All value of template_id has one element in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend the following approach to do this

1. Create a new field `temp_template_id` with datatype `int`
2. Insert all the values of the `template_id` to the `temp_template_id`
3. Remove column `template_id`
4. Rename column `temp_template_id` to `template_id`

a. rails g migration AddTempTemplateDataToTableName

```
def change
  add_column :table_name, :temp_template_id, :integer
end
```

b. rails g migration RenameColumnTemptemplateID

```
def self.up
  # Script to fill column `temp_template_id` from 'template_id'
  remove_column :table_name, :template_id
  rename_column :table_name, :temp_template_id, :template_id
end

def self.down      
  rename_column :table_name, :template_id, :temp_template_id
  add_column :table_name, :template_id, :array, :default => []
  # Script to fill column `template_id` from 'temp_template_id'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the SQL migration would be as easy as `using n[1]`:

```
t=# create table t3(n int[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t3 select array[2];
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from t3;
  n
-----
 {2}
(1 row)

t=# alter table t3 alter COLUMN n type int using n[1];
ALTER TABLE
t=# select * from t3;
 n
---
 2
(1 row)
```

and in case you had array not as `int[]`, you will need double cast to avoiod

> ERROR: result of USING clause for column "template_id" cannot be cast
>   automatically to type integer HINT: You might need to add an explicit
>   cast.

```
alter table t3 alter COLUMN n type int using n[1]::text::int;
```

should do the trick, here's example:

```
t=# create table t3(n text[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t3 select array[2];
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from t3;
  n
-----
 {2}
(1 row)

t=# alter table t3 alter COLUMN n type int using n[1]::text::int;
ALTER TABLE
t=# select * from t3;
 n
---
 2
(1 row)
```

Comment: ERROR:  result of USING clause for column "template_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to add an explicit cast.   Here template_id is 'n'

Comment: try adding `::text::int` as in my asnwer